# Why isn't this simple PHP expression working?

Tags: php

```
    $links = array('https://google.com', 'http://aloe.com', 'http://foobar.org/image.jpg');

    foreach ($links as $link)
    {
            $unacceptables = array('https:','.doc','.pdf', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.bmp', '.png');
            foreach ($unacceptables as $unacceptable)
            {
                if (strpos($link, $unacceptable) !== false)
                {
                        echo 'not acceptable!<br />';
                }
                else
                {
                        echo 'acceptable<br />';
                }
            }
    }
```

The above should output:

```
not acceptable
acceptable
not acceptable
```

But instead if outputs this mess:

```
not acceptable!
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
not acceptable!
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
acceptable
```

How to get it to work right?

Comment: Your if-else is being run for *every* `$unacceptable` for *every* `$link`.

Comment: There are 3 links, the first foreach will run 3 times. There are 8 unacceptables, the second foreach will run 8 times. The inner loop echo's "acceptable" or "not acceptable" on every run. 3 * 8 = 24 lines of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you got loop inside a loop (and that's why it outputs 8 * 3 = 24 times).
You need to introduce a variable $is_accepted, set the variable inside the inner loop and output the answer inside the outer but not inside the inner loop.

```
  $links = array('https://google.com', 'http://aloe.com', 'http://foobar.org/image.jpg');

foreach ($links as $link)
{
        $unacceptables = array('https:','.doc','.pdf', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.bmp', '.png');
    $is_accepted = true;
        foreach ($unacceptables as $unacceptable)
        {
            if (strpos($link, $unacceptable) !== false)
            {
                    $is_accepted = false;
            }
        }

    if (!$is_accepted)
        {
            echo 'not acceptable!<br />';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'acceptable<br />';
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to have only one output per resource, and not one per resource and unacceptable (cartesian product!)

try this:

```
$isAcceptable = true;
foreach ( $unacceptables as $unaccetable )
{
    if (strpos($link, $unacceptable) !== false)
    {
        $isAcceptable = false;
        break; // not acceptable, no more checks needed
    }
}
echo ($isAcceptable ? 'acceptable' : 'not acceptable');
```

instead of your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$links = array('https://google.com', 'http://aloe.com', 'http://foobar.org/image.jpg');

foreach ($links as $link)
{
        $unacceptables = array('https:','.doc','.pdf', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.bmp', '.png');
        $accept = true;
        foreach ($unacceptables as $unacceptable)
        {
            if (strpos($link, $unacceptable) !== false)
            {
                    $accept = false;
            }
        }

        if ($accept == true) {
            echo "Acceptable<br />";
        } else {
            echo "Not acceptable<br />";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correction to your code, while maintaining most of the code that you wrote:

```
$links = array('https://google.com', 'http://aloe.com', 'http://foobar.org/image.jpg');

foreach ($links as $link)
{
        $unacceptables = array('https:','.doc','.pdf', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.bmp', '.png');
        $link_is_acceptable = true;
        foreach ($unacceptables as $unacceptable)
        {
            if (strpos($link, $unacceptable) !== false){
                $link_is_acceptable = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($link_is_acceptable)
        {
                echo 'acceptable<br />';
        }
        else
        {
                echo 'not acceptable!<br />';
        }
}
```